# Does IDragHandler only works on canvas and UI items?

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop, unity-game-engine

I've followed an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c47QYgsJrWc) about drag & drop items using `UnityEngine.EventSystems` and it works.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private Transform startParent;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPosition = transform.position;
        startParent = transform.parent;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
        if (transform.parent == startParent)
            transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

But the same code doesn't work if I add the script component to a sprite out of the canvas. So I have to use this code to drag & drop sprites.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 offset;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {

        offset = gameObject.transform.position -
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 4f));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 4f);
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newPosition) + offset;
    }
}
```

But this way I can't detect if a gameobject has been dropped to another, which can be done by `IDropHandler.OnDrop` in canvas.

So In Unity do I have to use IDragHandler and EventSystem only on canvas and UI items?

Is there any alternatives for detecting dropped items in an gameobject without using canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDragHandler -> interface` in `UnityEngine.EventSystems` 
Implements `interfaces: IEventSystemHandler -> base` class that all `EventSystem` events inherit from.

Class in `UnityEngine.EventSystems` inherits from: ***EventSystems.UIBehaviour***

So… `IDragHandler` and `EventSystem` work ***only*** on canvas and UI items.

Comment: No and Not 

you can see that !! [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/991083/dragging-a-2d-sprite-with-touch.html)